# How to count a charater in textarea used with fckeditor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, fckeditor

I'm using `textarea` and on page load change it into html `textbox` using fck editor

```
var oFCKeditor = new FCKeditor('Simplify');
oFCKeditor.BasePath = "/Content/fckeditor/";
oFCKeditor.Height = 400;oFCKeditor.ReplaceTextarea();
```

So  let me know how can I count `char`s of that type.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Do you need it server side or client side and what `char` do you want to count?

Comment: client side .. and i just convert the textarea into html textarea but i also want to count the character that type thr

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the text that is inside the FCKEDitor editable area easily, see these two docs:

http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Integration

http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/jQuery_Adapter

Once you have the contents of the textarea you can loop over the text and count characters, words, whatever as it is a string.